# length of a just one array dimension in minizinc

Tags: minizinc

If I define my array like this:

```
array[_, 1..2] of J: A;
```

where J is a enum, what function can I use to get the length of the first dimension of A? The `length` function returns 14 (and states that it doesn't work for multiple dimensions). I had it hard-coded like so in my testing, but it won't always be 13:

```
constraint forall(row in 1..13)(S[A[row, 2]] >= C[A[row, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length function is really only meant for getting the number of elements. When you want the retrieve indexes of an array, you should instead use the `index_set` function. This returns the actual index set, which you can iterate over: `i in index_set(A)`

For multidimensional arrays there are specific functions for each index set of the array. For example, to get the first index set from a two-dimensional array (as in your code fragment) you can use the function `index_set_1of2`